# Why am i getting an error at invoking getCounter method?

Tags: java

this is my full code

```
package user;
public class User {
private String userID,emailAddress;
private int numOfAccesses;
public static int counter=0;
public User(String iD,String emailA,int nOA){
userID=iD;
emailA=emailAddress;
nOA=numOfAccesses;
counter++  
}
public User(String aID,String aEmail){
this(aID,aEmail,0);
}
public User(){
this(null,null,0); 
}
public String getInfos(){
String message =("user ID "+userID+"\n"+"email address is "+emailAddress+"\n"+"number of accesses "+numOfAccesses);
return message;
}   

public void  setInfos(String setID,String setEmail){
   setID=userID;
   setEmail=emailAddress;

}
public int getCounter(){
return counter;

}
 public void updateNumOfAccesses(){
   numOfAccesses++;

 }
  public class testUser extends User{
    User user1=new User();
    System.out.println("counter is "+user1.getCounter);

 } 
public static void main(String[] args) {

}

   }
```

I am sorry I am a noob in java but I'm really confused why can't I invoke getCounter method while I clearly made it right . is it because inheritance? or didn't I use the counter right? please help

Comment: You need to format your code. This is very hard to read.

Comment: And what do you mean "why can't I invoke getCounter method"? I don't know, what's stopping you? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Because your println isn't in a method body or initializer block. Also, `setInfos` has swapped the order of fields and parameters (you don't want to set the parameters, you want to set the fields).

Comment: Also you have a syntax error, you want `System.out.println("counter is "+user1.getCounter ());` as you are calling a method

Comment: sorry .. yea I am getting "cannot find symbol error" when invoking getCounter

Comment: Also, you can't declare more than one top-level `public` class in the same file.

Comment: AND AGAIN we have users that ask questions and keeping asking for an insane amount of details and then do not even upvote or accept an asnswer

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error

you want

```
System.out.println("counter is "+user1.getCounter ());
```

as you are calling a method

Also change this code

```
 public class testUser extends User{
    User user1=new User();
    System.out.println("counter is "+user1.getCounter);

 } 
 public static void main(String[] args) {

 }
```

to

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    User user1=new User();
    System.out.println("counter is "+user1.getCounter ());
}
```

**Another error** is

```
counter++  is not terminated with a `;`
```

Comment: comon man I told you I am a noob don't make fun of me .. instead tell me what could I do

Comment: and please tell me how can I fix this?

Comment: who are you directing your comments towards?

Comment: sorry .. forgot to mention @shmosel

Comment: @shmosel says that my problem I asked about is the least of my problems but he doesn't tell me what i did wrong .. also the code runs perfectly so I am confused

Comment: @JeenzooKT I wasn't making fun of you. I was saying that this answer only addressed one small problem of many.

Comment: what problems? what is wrong with the code apart of what I asked ? @shmosel

Comment: @shmosel *That's the least of his problems* - maybe all compile errors should be evenly weighted?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Perhaps. Or they could be weighed by what they say about the author's understanding.

Comment: @shmosel Fixed my careless cut-and-paste

Comment: parentheses? which ones?

Comment: Sorry when I edited my question I cut-and-pasted your original error (no parentheses on the getCounter method call) - I have now fixed it so please read my answer

Comment: ok I changed it but i am getting "accessing static field counter" and the code gives an exception and does not work

Comment: look I can give you what the homework asking me it is

Comment: Develop a public class TestUsers to the following specifications:
1. The class has the static main method
2. Create user1 as an instance object of User class using the multi-argument constructor.
3. Print the counter using the user1 object notation and class notation.

Comment: what can I do to print the counter as asked

Comment: See my latest edit.  This code works for me.  **Now** relating to you assignment, note that each `public` class needs to be in its own file e.g. TestUser needs to be declared in TestUser.java  If you make this file you can *copy* the method `main` from `User` to `TestUser` and then run `TestUser`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class User {
    ...

    class TestUser extends User {
        User user1 = new User();

        public void someMethodName() {
            System.out.println("counter is " + user1.getCounter());
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User u1 = new User();
        TestUser tu1 = u1.new TestUser();
        tu1.someMethodName();
    }

}
```

Output:

```
counter is 3
```

As you are invoking User() creation three times.

1. User u1 = new User(); // counter = 1
2. TestUser tu1 = u1.new TestUser(); // counter = 3
   Here when the JVM sees `extends User` it calls the constructor of `User` class which increments the counter.
   Then, `User user1 = new User();` once again increments the counter

Comment: Why use an inner class?

Comment: I forgot to mention that in the answer. It was as per OP's original code. I guess he wanted to make use of inner class but had declared it public in his code.

Comment: It's far more likely that OP doesn't know the difference between a static and inner class. It's not even clear he really wants another class altogether.

Comment: ok ok I don't know what OP means but I will give you the section of homework I am confused about and please do tell me how to do it in its best form ... Develop a public class TestUsers to the following specifications: 1. The class has the static main method 2. Create user1 as an instance object of User class using the multi-argument constructor. 3. Print the counter using the user1 object notation and class notation

Comment: I know it does increment the counter that's how they asked me to do it

Comment: @JeenzooKT OP means "original poster" (you). To follow the specification, you'll need to create `TestUsers` as a separate class file, with your code in its `main()` method.

Comment: but how can I use privates in the other class? it won't let me change anything in it

Comment: `public int getCounter()` is not `private` - see my edited answer